# MSBuild Extension Pack: Credentials for File/Folder tasks?

Tags: .net, msbuild, permissions

Good afternoon,

say is it possible to provide credentials (username/pw) for file or folder activities (e.g. removecontent) with the MSBuild Extension Pack? As in.. the build user is not necessary the one I want to use to deleted/work with on certain folders/files I need to modify/delete (e.g. remotely on UNC shares).

Is this doable? I am somewhat lost :-/

Cheers and thanks,

-J

Answer (score 2):

`RemoveContent` task and the other folder tasks of MSBuild Extension pack use `DirectoryInfo` internally.

To access remote folder `DirectoryInfo` handles `UNC path`, the problem is that you can't put the credential in a `UNC path`. So you can't do what you want directly using only `RemoveContent` task.

### Workarounds :

- The simple one : Give the right to your build agent
- The better : Map the folder to a network drive and use this network drive in your MSBuild task. This can be done with MSBuild `Exec` task and `net` command

  ```
  <Target Name="MapAndRemove">
    <!-- Map the remote folder with credential -->
    <Exec Command="net use Z: \\ServerName\ShareName\YourFolder {Password} /user:{User} /yes"/>

    <!-- Remove content in remote folder using network drive -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Folder TaskAction="RemoveContent" 
                                             Path="Z:\"/>
  </Target>
  ```
- The harder : Write a MSBuild custom task doing what you want and that takes credential as parameters.